# Alphabetically Bubble Sort strings from different structs

Tags: c, function, struct, malloc, bubble-sort

So I am working on this project, in which I am required to alphabetically sort the strings in the allocated memory using a Bubble Sort. I am confused as to how to do this. I tried something that I thought would work, however it did not and I am currently at a loss.

Here is my bubble sort function:

```
void sort_customers (int num_customers, float *data_set)
{
    float counter, current, swap_temp = data_set;
         
    struct customer customer_1, customer_2, customer_3;
                  
    for (customer = 0; customer < num_customers-1; customer++)
        for(inner = customer+1; inner < num_customers; inner++)
        {
            if (strcmp(customer.last_name, inner.last_name) < 0)
            {
               strcpy (swap_temp, customer.last_name);
               strcpy (customer.last_name, inner.last_name);
               strcpy (inner.last_name, customer.last_name);
            }
         }
    return;
}
```

Comment: The code does not make sense.

Comment: What's `customer`?  What's `inner`? How can they be used both as arithmetic types and as structure types?

Comment: How does it make sense to assign pointer `data_set` to `float` variable `swap_temp`?  Did you mean to declare the latter as a pointer?  But even if you did, why are you using a `float` (or array of them) as temporary storage for a *string* swap?

Comment: And at a higher level, are you sure you want to swap the `last_name` fields among different structures, as opposed to swapping the whole structures?  It would make more sense to sort the structures by last name than to shuffle around *just* the last names, but it is the latter that you seem to be trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some errors in your code:

1. You cannot assign a `float *` to a `float` (`swap_temp = data_set`)
2. `customer` is undefined in the outer `for` loop
3. `inner` is undefined in the inner `for` loop
4. Assuming the `last_name` field of the `customer` struct is a char array, you cannot `strcpy` it to a `float` (`swap_temp`)
5. Not an error, but `strcmp` only compares the *ASCII* value of the two char arrays, and I don't think that's what you want (capitalization)
6. Not an error, but `counter` and `current` are never used
7. In the outer for loop, it seems that `customer` and `inner` are arithmetic types, but you try to get a "last_name" field from them inside the if-statement

I wrote a bubble sort program that sorts the names of "customers", and maybe this might help you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

struct customer {
    /*
     * Some other data...
     */
    char last_name[20];
};

/* Returns 1 if a > b (alphabetically), 0 otherwise, -1 if same */
int alpha_compare(char *a, char *b, size_t a_size, size_t b_size)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < a_size && i < b_size; i++) {
        if (tolower(a[i]) > tolower(b[i])) {
            return 1;
        } else if (tolower(a[i]) < tolower(b[i])) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    
    return -1;
}

void bubble_sort(struct customer *customer_list, size_t num_customers)
{
    struct customer swap_buf;
    short swap = 1;
    while (swap) {
        swap = 0;
        for (size_t i = 1; i < num_customers; i++) {
            switch (alpha_compare(customer_list[i-1].last_name, customer_list[i].last_name, 20, 20)) {
                case 1:
                    {
                        swap_buf = customer_list[i-1];
                        customer_list[i-1] = customer_list[i];
                        customer_list[i] = swap_buf;
                        swap = 1;
                    }
                default: break;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    // These are example "last names"
    struct customer c1 = {"tower"};
    struct customer c2 = {"tree"};
    struct customer c3 = {"banana"};
    struct customer c4 = {"bird"};
    struct customer c5 = {"apple"};

    struct customer customer_list[] = {c1, c2, c3, c4, c5};

    bubble_sort(customer_list, 5);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", customer_list[i].last_name);
    }
}
```

Wikipedia provides a nice overlook of the [Bubble sort algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) if you need it.